# How to clear TimePicker editText?

Tags: android, datetime, android-edittext, onactivityresult

In **Activity B**, I have two clickable `editText`(TI,TO), and one save `Button`. When `EditText` is clicked, `TimePicker dialog` will be shown. Save `Button` used to return this two value to **Activity A.**

The problem now is the `EditText` will display the latest value get from `TimePicker dialog` on Activity A **even no value is selected on Activity B** .

Let's said in **Activity B** , I have entered `1:00` on TI and `2:00` in TO. In second times, I didn't enter anything on the Activity B `EditText` and press button to return to A, it still will display 1:00 and 2:00 on Activity A.

**Activity B**

```
      timeIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { //shows timePick
                    Fragment fragDialog = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TimePicker");
                    if (fragDialog == null) { // Fragment not added
                        tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_START_DATE);
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
                    } else {

                        // already active
                    }
                }
            });

            timeOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Fragment fragDialog = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TimePicker");
                    if(fragDialog == null)
                    {  // Fragment not added
                        tp.setFlag(TimePick.FLAG_END_DATE);
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        tp.show(ft, "TimePicker");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // already active
                    }
                }
            });

  public static class TimePick extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        public static final int FLAG_START_DATE = 00;
        public static final int FLAG_END_DATE = 01;
        private int flag = 00;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void setFlag(int i) {
            flag = i;
        }


        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourofDay, int minute) {

            if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE) {
                T1.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                TimeIn = T1.getText().toString();
            }
            if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE) {
                TO.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                TimeOut = TO.getText().toString();
            }

        }

  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {  // return values to A activity
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("TimeIn", TimeIn);
                returnIntent.putExtra("TimeOut",TimeOut);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

**Activity A**

```
       @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                        ReceiveTimeIn = data.getStringExtra("TimeIn");
                        ReceiveTimeOut = data.getStringExtra("TimeOut");
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ReceiveTimeIn+ReceiveTimeOut,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
```

The `Toast` suppose to display `null` for the second time, but it display `1:00 2:00` instead.

**Edited** (Activity B)

```
  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // return values to  activity A

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v)
                 {
                      if (isEdited == false)
                      {
                          if(T1!=null||TO!=null) // if editText not clicked but has value pass from ListView A
                          {
                              // return T1 and TO value to listView Activity A
                          }
                          else { // if editText not clicked and no value passed, then only null
                              TimeIn = "";
                              TimeOut = "";
                          }
                      }

                 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                 Project = project.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 Description = description.getText().toString();
                 progress = seekBar.getProgress();
                 returnIntent.putExtra("Project", Project);
                 returnIntent.putExtra("Description", Description);
                 returnIntent.putExtra("progress", progress);
                 returnIntent.putExtra("TimeIn", TimeIn);
                 returnIntent.putExtra("TimeOut", TimeOut);
                 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                 finish();
                 }
          });
```

Comment: So what you can do is second time when you opening activity B, on openinf of activity make both edittext empty so if you haven't selectd any edittext it would show any value in edittext

Comment: how can I make both editText empty on the second time ?

Comment: put it on **ActivityB** `onCreate()` ?

Comment: after declaration of findViewById of both edittext.

Comment: It still display ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97893/discussion-between-clairvoyant-and-seng).

Comment: @Clairvoyant sorry to bother you again. I use your code given and it works fine since it will clear the editText for second time and still will remain the editText value if listView is clicked. But I having another problem now. If I clicked the listView, and it has `1:00` and `2:00` on both editText in Activity B. Now I click save button back to A, I want it still return this two value in Activity A instead of changing to null .

Comment: Not understand seng what you want to do

Comment: @Clairvoyant If I click the list, the `1:00` and `2:00` will display on editText Activity B. But when I click the save button, it return null to list Activity A. I'm sure is because of  `if (isEdited == false)
                      {
                          TimeIn = "";
                          TimeOut = "";
                      }`.  How do I make it to check if the EditText not press but has value on two editText, when return, it will display two value on Activity A instead of null?

Comment: @Clairvoyant check my post again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `findViewById` of both `timeIn and timeOut edittext` set them empty as follows:

```
timeIn.setText(""); 
timeOut.setText("");
```

And your other two variable also:

```
TimeIn = "";
TimeOut = "";
```